# How to get R plotly to separate thousands with comma?

Tags: r, plotly

Thousand commas won't load

Using scales library - labels = comma

```
plot_ly(x = ecomm_yoy2$YOY, y = ecomm_yoy2$Brand, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h', color = ~ecomm_yoy2$YOY < 0, colors = c("steelblue", "red"), name = ~ifelse(ecomm_yoy2$YOY < 0, "< 0", ">= 0")) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "YOY change in £")) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = ecomm_yoy2$YOY, categoryorder = "array")) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_annotations(text = ecomm_yoy2$YOY, showarrow = F, xshift = 25)
```

No error messages but commas not applied.